# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<<anonymous type:

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, foreach

```
var contacts = (from c in _db.Contacts
                join dgm in _db.DistributionGroupMembers on c.Id equals dgm.ContactId
                join dg in _db.DistributionGroups on dgm.DistributionGroupId equals dg.Id
                join dgis in _db.DistributionGroupInSms on dg.Id equals dgis.DistributionGroupId
                where dgis.SmsId == SmsId
                select new
                {
                    id = c.Id,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber,
                    Result = "Waiting to be sent"
                }).Distinct().ToArrayAsync();

foreach (var contact in contacts) //contacts is underlined
{
    recipients.Recipients.Add(new RecipientsInSmsData() { Id = contact.id,
        FirstName = contact.FirstName,
        LastName = contact.LastName,
        PhoneNumber = contact.PhoneNumber,
        SendingResult = contact.SendingResult
    });
}
```

Compiler error message:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<[]>' because 'Task<[]>'
>   does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

between the <>'s after task it says:

anonymous type: int id, string FirstName, string LastName, string PhoneNumber, string Result

Comment: Dont use `var` in `var contacts` and you will see your issue...  Things that are `async` need to be `await` -ed so you can get the result of the task and not the task itself

Comment: if you don't mind immediate execution you can replace ToArrayAsync() with ToList(), then foreach will operate on a list instead of a task array

Comment: @barrypicker Why would  you suggest creating a List that won't be used? An array makes much more sense here

Comment: @barrypicker, Thanks. I changed it to ToList() and it seems to work. THank you

Comment: @josibu That's a terrible suggestion, you are losing all the benefits of asynchronous programming

Comment: @josibu this isnt the crux of your problem.  You need to await the async call, not just call `ToList()`

Comment: Just write `var contacts = await (from c …).ToArrayAsync();` and everything will work fine.

Comment: @maccettura regarding your first post, what to use instead of var? I tried several variants of Task

Comment: @poke and maccettura, the await statement did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @josibu use the actual type.  VS should give you the ability to change that.  You dont actually have to change it though, my point was that using `var` hid what the type was and had you seen that it was a `Task<T>` you would know you cannot iterate it

Comment: You also don't need to project to an anonymous type, just do `select new RecipientsInSmsData { ... }` and remove that from the `foreach`

Comment: @josibu listen to Camilo here.  The anonymous object is completely wasteful. You can skip the `foreach` entirely when you do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous operations need to be `await`ed in order to get the result, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) is a great starting point for learning how to use `async` and `await`.
The other problem here is that the `foreach` is unnecessary if LINQ is used properly:

```
var contacts = await (
            from c in _db.Contacts
            join dgm in _db.DistributionGroupMembers on c.Id equals dgm.ContactId
            join dg in _db.DistributionGroups on dgm.DistributionGroupId equals dg.Id
            join dgis in _db.DistributionGroupInSms on dg.Id equals dgis.DistributionGroupId
            where dgis.SmsId == SmsId
            select new RecipientsInSmsData
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber,
                Result = "Waiting to be sent"
            })
            .Distinct()
            .ToArrayAsync();

recipients.Recipients.AddRange(contacts);
```